# What's the meaning of this C++ syntax

Tags: c++, dbus

I found this c++ code but I can't understand this syntax:

```
auto path_dbus = [&](DBus::Connection &bus) {
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a lambda function that:

- captures any used variables by reference `[&]`
- takes an argument `(DBus::Connection&)`
- does some work `{...}`

To break down that line:

```
auto path_dbus = [&]      (DBus::Connection &bus) {... };
                 ^capture ^arguments              ^work
```

Comment: "everything currently in scope" is misleading. Only those used are captured. (§5.1.2[expr.prim.lambda]/11)

Comment: @RJFalconer Isn't that an implementation detail?

Comment: @eush77 there's a [nicely-written explanation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293603.aspx), scroll to "Capture clause" (specifically "`A common misconception about capture-default is that all variables in the scope are captured whether they are used in the lambda or not`")

Comment: @RJFalconer Sorry, could you elaborate a bit more? This behavior is defined in §5.1.2 and hence is technically not an implementation detail (and my original comment is wrong) but as a user of the language I can't tell whether all variables are captured or only those used, can I? Your link doesn't explain why this misconception is worth worrying about.